# Does a local Android Firestore instance sync its internal clock with the server?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The reason I ask is because we know that local writes to Firestore are instant. Meaning that locally written objects can be queried instantly. We are also told by the documentation that there is a [ServerTimestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/ServerTimestamp) annotation.

> **ServerTimestamp**
>
> public abstract @interface ServerTimestamp implements Annotation
>
> Annotation used to mark a timestamp field to be populated
> with a server timestamp. If a POJO being written contains null for a
> @ServerTimestamp-annotated field, it will be replaced with a
> server-generated timestamp.

It sounds like if an object field is so annotated, and the object written locally, then queried locally, then the field would contain the `current server timestamp`. Of course this would mean that the local Firestore instance, at some point, synced its clock with the server. Is this true?

If true, then such a trick could be used to query the current Firebase server time, effectively synching clocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behavior for server timestamps written to a document, read back before the document is synchronized, is simply a null value.  You can change this behavior with [`ServerTimestampBehavior`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot.ServerTimestampBehavior).  Pass one if its enums to [`getData()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot#getData%28com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot.ServerTimestampBehavior%29) to get one of the following:

- ESTIMATE

> Return local estimates for ServerTimestamps that have not yet been set
>   to their final value. This estimate will likely differ from the final
>   value and may cause these pending values to change once the server
>   result becomes available.

The estimated value is derived from what the client SDK believes to be the current time, using the local clock. When the write is fully committed, the timestamp will likely change to be the actual server value.

- PREVIOUS

> Return the previous value for ServerTimestamps that have not yet been
>   set to their final value.

Comment: Do you know if the estimated timestamp is calculated using the [Clock Skew](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#clock-skew) mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Android Firestore documentation exposes the [Clock Skew](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#clock-skew)

> **Clock Skew**
>
> While firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP is much more
> accurate, and preferable for most read/write operations, it can
> occasionally be useful to estimate the client's clock skew with
> respect to the Firebase Realtime Database's servers. You can attach a
> callback to the location /.info/serverTimeOffset to obtain the value,
> in milliseconds, that Firebase Realtime Database clients add to the
> local reported time (epoch time in milliseconds) to estimate the
> server time. Note that this offset's accuracy can be affected by
> networking latency, and so is useful primarily for discovering large
> (> 1 second) discrepancies in clock time.

```
DatabaseReference offsetRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(".info/serverTimeOffset");
offsetRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    double offset = snapshot.getValue(Double.class);
    double estimatedServerTimeMs = System.currentTimeMillis() + offset;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
    System.err.println("Listener was cancelled");
  }
});
```

This could be a sufficient way to sync clocks.